# c++ finding the state of a sibling

Tags: c++

In my code, there's a base class A which has three subclasses A1, A2, A3. These objects have a state to specify if they are active or not.

Now in another class B , objects of A1, A2, and A3 are created. Now in a function inside B,

```
int B::SetState( A& aObj)
{
  //if aObj is an instance of A1, do nothing and return.
  //if aObj is an instance of A2, do something if A3 is active 
  //if aObj is an instance of A3, do something if A2 is active 

  //the code below i would like to change to something more maintainable
  if ( aObj.GetNumber() == 0 )
      return;

  A& otherAObj = aObj.GetNumber()==1? GetAObj(2) : GetAObj(3);

  if ( otherAObj.IsActive() )
  {
    //do something with aObj
  }

}
```

I would like to change the code to something like aObj.DoSomething() but the dependency between sibling is making it tough. Any other good ideas to refactor? The class structure has to remain the same.

Comment: When you say "if aObj contain A1", do you mean "if A is an instance of class A1"? If yes, you may want to do a search on double dispatch and the Visitor pattern.

Comment: a) you can use RTTI, if performance is not an issue. b) if you can alter A, A1, A2, A3 then use a virtual function and override it in derived classes. Then all that u need is to make one aObj.DoSomething()

Comment: If you're doing conditional behaviour at the *call* site based on object type, then you probably do need to refactor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor this:

```
if ( otherAObj.IsActive() )
{
  //do something with aObj
}
```

out into a doSomething() function

```
public class A{
    virtual bool isActive(){ return false; }
    virtual bool isPending(){ return false; }
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        if(true == isActive())
        {
            ...
            if(false == isPending())
            { ... }
            ...
        }
    };
}

public class A_State_Active : A
{
    bool isActive(){ return true; }
}

public class A_State_Pending : A
{
    bool isPending(){ return true; }
    void doSomething()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't be messing");
    }
}
```

Or even make the base version of doSomething pure virtual to force the users to implement a state specific version.

However you should not implement anything in your subclasses that is based on the state of a different object. IMO you should use a manager type object in that case. If really want to do it that way you should just pass a reference to the other objects to the `doSomething()` function and modify the runtime behaviour based on the return values of the passed object's state (query using the "isActive"/"isPending" API).

Other option is to do away with inheritance and favour composition. Have `A` be one class which holds a reference to an `A_State` class. You then subclass `A_State`.

```
class A
{
    //public functions
    ...
    const A_State* getState(){ return m_poMyState; }
    void setState(const A_State const * aStateObj ){ m_poMyState = aStateObj; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enhance the A interface with functions like

```
virtual bool hasSibling() const = 0;
virual int siblingNumber() const = 0;
```

Then, given suitable implementations in the subclasses the B code can do:

```
if (!aObj.hasSibling()) return;
A & otherObj = GetAObj(aObj.siblingNumber());
if (otherObj.isActive()) { ... }
```

It'd be better if you could push some more of the logic down into A (on the tell don't ask principle), but that may be tricky with GetAObj residing on B.